# Why is this not assigning the correct value?

Tags: python, recursion, fibonacci

I wanted to store the biggest fib number calculated so  far, but the variable biggest is not being assigned to correctly.

```
cache = {}
biggest = 1
def fib(n):
  if n == 0:
    return 0
  if n == 1:
    return 1

  if not n in cache:
    cache[n] = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
    print "calculated %ith fib giving %i" %(n, cache[n])
    biggest = cache[n]

  return cache[n]
```

After doing fib(10), the cache looks good, but biggest is still 1. Sorry for the beginner question, but was hoping someone could enlighten me. Thanks!

Comment: And technically you're returning **biggest** after calling the `fib(n)` which makes **biggest** a little redundant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare the `biggest` as a global using [`global` statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement) (especially when there's an assignment to the variable). Otherwise, it is treated as a local variable.

```
cache = {}
biggest = 1

def fib(n):
    global biggest  # <-----
    ....
```

Comment: why the global? whereas OP already used **cache** within the same module, can also access **biggest**.

Comment: @Anzel, `cache` is used as read-only. In other word, there's no assignment to `cache`; `cache` is considered global. While, There's a assignment to `biggest`; considered local (unless there's global statement)

Comment: @Anzel, I updated the answer to mention about assignment to clarify. Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: ah I see where this is coming from, I thought OP code didn't work. It works but trying to `print biggest` after calling the function. Apologized I didn't pay enough attention

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to be doing this in Python >= 3.2 some day, you can also use `lru_cache`

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache()
def fibo(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return 1
    return fibo(n-1) + fibo(n-2)
```

`lru_cache` allows your to cache something **exactly** the way you're trying to do, but automatically, much faster, and without you having to do anything. Just using this decorator.

**[Documentation here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache)**.

Comment: OP is using Python 2.x (using `print` as a statement). [`functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) is available since Python 3.2.

Comment: Oh god... Well. That's a problem.

Comment: And, OP is not asking about memoization.